# duplicate values in a row using pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i have this query:

```
SELECT distinct
    num as number,
    name as name
    from my_table_name 
 where number = '12345';
```

And this is the results:

```
    number - name

 1. 12345 - mike
 2. 12345 - charlie
 3. 12345 - jose
```

I need a new query when this happens (numbers duplicate or triplicate) show me only one of them. Example:

```
   number - name
   12345 - mike
```

I only need one of them; the position doesn't matter. If it find one, print this and close the procedure, function or cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct is going to return results that are distinct, relative to all of the data you are querying for.  If you only want one of the results returned and you know that the result used is arbitrary, you can just add [a filter based on the row number](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) (how specifically this is done depends on what DBMS you are using.)

Oracle example:

```
select num as "number",
       name as "name"
  from my_table_name 
 where number = '12345'
   and rownum = 1; -- just gets the first row.
```

Comment: Thanks for the polish-up to the answer, Ben. :)

Answer (score 0):

use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    select id, name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition by id order by name asc) as seq
    from tableA
    where number = '12345'
) T
where T.seq =1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from 
     (SELECT rownum rnum,
        num as number,
        name as name
        FROM my_table_name 
     WHERE number = '12345' )
WHERE rnum = 1
```

Comment: This is not valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: That will return N - 1 rows rather than 1. Did you mean `where rnum = 1`?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the questions for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which one is being returned, why are you even asking for it to be returned?

However, to get a single line of results regardless of the number of matching rows, you should probably be using `GROUP BY` and a summary function:

```
Select 
 num as number, 
 max(name) as name --or min(), or any other summary function that works on this data type
from my_table_name
where num = '12345'
group by num
```